# Page doesn't postback if it has validation control after deployment

Tags: asp.net

I have a page with a RadioButtonList which should post back when the selection is changed. But because of RequiredFieldValidator on the page, the postback is not happening.
It is working fine on //localhost/ but not after deployment to production server.

The error on the page is:
'event' is null or not an object

Line: 126
Char: 5
Code: 0

URI: http://web-dev:90/aspnet_client/system_web/2_0_50727/WebUIValidation.js

A few things which I have already tried:

1) aspnet_client folder is in its proper place.

2) I have added `Page.Validate() and if(Page.IsValid){}` statements with the button on whose click the validation should happen.

3) The ValidatorCommonOnSubmit function in `WebUIValidation.js` file looks like this:

```
   function ValidatorCommonOnSubmit() {
    event.returnValue = !Page_BlockSubmit;
   Page_BlockSubmit = false;
   return event.returnValue;}
```

Can somebody help me with this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can group the required field validator related controls so that it wont effect the radio button list.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" runat="server" ValidationGroup="button1"
        ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" ValidationGroup="button1"  />
```

As far as your radio button list is **not** grouped under "button1" group, it will not have any problem.

Details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070106/isolate-a-required-field-validator)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found the solution. I made EnableClientScript property of the validator control false. The validation controls are firing now and Postback is happening.